# Double precision error in R

Tags: r, precision, floating-accuracy

In my code there exists a step during likelihood calculation where I need to evaluate exponent of -ve numbers and take the logarithm after adding such exponents. For e.g.

```
> log(exp(-2500))
[1] -Inf
> log(exp(-2500)+exp(-3000))
[1] -Inf
```

Due to high absolute value of these -ve numbers, it turns out the exp(-ve number) goes to zero (as expected). But, the logarithm which is evaluated at a later step takes zero as the input. Any way to avoid these erroneous outputs in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate *logarithms* of likelihoods. Store them in a vector `v`. Then calculate

```
m = max(v)
logsum = log(sum(exp(v-m)))+m
```

Comment: Isn't that an approximate method?  For e.g. `> log(exp(-10)+exp(-100))
[1] -10
> log(exp(-log(10))+exp(-log(100)))
[1] -2.207275
> exp(-2.207275)
[1] 0.11`

Comment: Oh..wait! are you referring something like `log(a + b) = log(a * (1 + b/a)) = log a + log(1 + b/a)`?

Comment: @kasa - yes to your second comment